# How to show this fact?

Tags: probability-theory

For any event $A$, how to prove that bound:
$$\mathbb{P}(A) \leq \mathbb{P}(A|B) + \mathbb{P}(\overline{B}) ?$$

Thanks

Comment: Hello and Welcome to MSE. Please try and have an informative title, and include context, what you've tried, and what you do and don't understand in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbb{P}(A)=\mathbb{P}(A|B)\mathbb{P}(B)+\mathbb{P}(A|B^c)\mathbb{P}(B^c)\leq\mathbb{P}(A|B)+\mathbb{P}(B^c)$

The "$\leq$" holds because $\mathbb{P}(B)\leq1$ and $\mathbb{P}(A|B^c)\leq 1$. Probability is always between $[0,1]$.

Comment: How $\mathbb{P}(A|B^{c}) - \mathbb{P}(A|B) \leq 1$

Comment: @Assoweh Updated.